# How to get parents of each removed node using jstree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I copied my working example into jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vvMaG/56/

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_lib/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.jstree.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
<input type="button" id="remove" value="remove" style="display:block; float:left;"/>
</div><br><br>
<div id="tree">
<ul>
    <li><a>List item one</a></li>
    <li><a>List item two with subitems:</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a>Subitem 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Subitem 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Final list item</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a>Subitem 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Subitem 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
            $("#tree")
                .jstree({
                    "plugins":["html_data","ui","themes","crrm"],
                    "themes" :{
                        "theme":"classic"
                    }
                })
                .bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
                    /*point 1 here*/
                    var parent=data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj);
                    console.log(parent.find('a').first().text());
                })
                .bind("remove.jstree", function (e, data){
                    /*point 2 here*/
                    var parent=data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj);
                    alert(parent.find('a').first().text());
                    /*point 3 here*/
                    data.rslt.obj.each(function () {
                        console.log(data.rslt.parent.children()[1].text);
                    });
                })
    });
    $(function () { 
        $("#menu input").click(function (){
            $("#tree").jstree(this.id);
        })
    });
</script>

</html>
```

When I select a node, it correctly gets the parent (point 1). However I suspect this method doesn't work when the node is removed as there is no parent for a node that has been removed (point 2) because I get a `parent.find is not a function` error.

The only way I know how to get the parent is by looping through `data.rslt.parent.children()` (point 3). However obviously this only gets the first parent as I'm going through the `rlst.parent` and not `data.rslt.obj`. There is no such `data.rslt.object.parent` that I know of when I have selected **multiple** nodes to delete.
Is there a way to get ALL parents of the deleted nodes?

Thanks

Comment: Not working reason : Timestamp: 11/4/2013 1:32:36 PM
Error: TypeError: this.data.html_data.original_container_html.find(...).addBack is not a function
Source File: https://raw.github.com/vakata/jstree/v.pre1.0/jquery.jstree.js
Line: 4018   ||  change your jQuery library version.  See : http://jsfiddle.net/vvMaG/52/

Comment: ah thanks, was using the wrong jstree. updated jsfiddle url.

Answer (score 0):

About your jsfiddle :

> Not working reason : Timestamp: 11/4/2013 1:32:36 PM
>
> Error:  TypeError:
>   this.data.html_data.original_container_html.find(...).addBack is not a
>   function Source File:
>   raw.github.com/vakata/jstree/v.pre1.0/jquery.jstree.js Line: 4018

change your jQuery library version. See : jsfiddle.net/vvMaG/52

About your other part, it will generate an error if there is no parent to element.

> Timestamp: 11/4/2013 1:42:03 PM Error: TypeError: parent.find is not a
>   function Source File: http://fiddle.jshell.net/vvMaG/54/show/ Line: 45

In your function,

```
...
.bind("remove.jstree", function (e, data){
                    var parent=data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj);
                    alert(parent.find('a').first().text());
                    data.rslt.obj.each(function () {
                        console.log(data.rslt.parent.children()[1].text);
                    });
                })
...
```

**Try:   parent().find('a')**  ( parent()  IS  a function,  parent  ISNOT)

Comment: Good. Now, your other situation. Did you get it ?

Comment: no, I am still unable to get the parents when I select both a node form "List item two with subitems:" and "Final list item", ie two nodes from two parents.

Comment: when I try parent().find('a'), it says TypeError: parent is not a function